# iOS static library compiled with Xcode remembers its source files

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I compiled a static library for iOS with Xcode with symbols stripped. It's compiled in the Release configuration. When I copy the static library into another iOS project (I physically copy it into another directory), I'm still able to view the source of the static library when stepping through code. I clicked *Show in finder* in the source window and it pointed me to the appropriate source file on disk.

I opened the library in a hex editor, and it indeed contains paths to my source files on my machine, as well as a bunch of other text data that that shouldn't be exposed.

Have I missed something in my project settings? If this is expected behavior, how can I make sure that the customer will not see the symbols, source file names etc.?

Comment: Don't ship the source to the "party to whom".

Comment: @HotLicks Source and symbols are two different things

Comment: change the folder of your source code (rename it) and try again, it won't find them this time

Comment: @BryanChen Thanks. This obviously works, but my library physically contains paths to files on my local disk (see edit). Is there a way to remove these altogether?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't use the right compiler options.  Of course, finding the right compiler options likely involves sacrificing a calf, or at least burning some incense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the compiler options required.

In LLVM code generation, set *Generate debug symbols* to **No** and *Symbols hidden by default* to **Yes**. For some reason, even if you tell it to strip symbols, it's not going to do it unless these are set.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can check whether symbols are striped or not using

   nm filename
2. Stripping doesn't happens automatically, you need to setup xcode to strip them and there are several flags that are in charge:

   a) [DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html)

   Prerequisite for: “STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT (Strip Linked Product).”

   b) STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT 
   This one is going to work in non-appstore builds only if you will have set DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING to YES.
3. There is a way to strip symbols manually, just call

   strip YOURBINARYNAME

Answer (score 1):

`strip YOURBINARYNAME` as suggested by @andrei-shender is not enough. You need to do the following:

```
strip -S YOURBINARYNAME
```

To get rid of the debugging symbols manually. Of course configuring your project properly is better, but if you are building a 3rd party library using a vendor script you may have to do it manually. Mapbox-native-gl goes from 550mb to 22mb if you strip the debug symbols!

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the stripped symbols using the strip command like the dsym file?

Comment: @Ravi I don't think that's possible.